# Insert picture using angular module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

- Is there a way to put some pictures using javascript and the angular module?
  I need to display the name of the object and the picture on its right side.

  - Where and how can I put the variable that will contain my picture location into the javascript code?

html code

```
<li class="animate-repeat" data-ng-repeat="object in objects | filter:q as results">
    [{{$index + 1}}] {{object.name}}
</li>
```

javascript code

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController', 
function($scope) {
    $scope.objects = [
    {name:'obj1'},
    {name:'obj2'},
    {name:'obj3'},
    {name:'obj4'}
  ];
});
})(window.angular);
```

I am trying to do something like this :

```
[{{$index + 1}}] {{object.name}} {{object.img}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<img>` element and bind the image url to the image's src attribute using `ng-src`.

```
<li class="animate-repeat" data-ng-repeat="object in objects | filter:q as results">
    [{{$index + 1}}] {{object.name}} <img data-ng-src="{{object.img}}" />
</li>
```

Then your Javascript should look like:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController',

        function($scope) {
            $scope.objects = [
                {name:'obj1', img: 'http://placehold.it/20'},
                {name:'obj2', img: 'http://placehold.it/20'},
                {name:'obj3', img: 'http://placehold.it/20'},
                {name:'obj4', img: 'http://placehold.it/20'}
            ];
        });
})(window.angular);
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0449dbdm/).

Comment: The picture doesn't display.

Comment: @Scanta I'm sorry. I forgot to add binding tags to ng-src. I have updated the answer. Also, I would avoid naming your module 'ngRepeat'. The AngularJS team recommends avoiding the 'ng' prefix in non official AngularJS code

Comment: Thanks, It works with online pictures but, can how I do it with a local picture?